# Как добавить путь в переменную $PATH?

Tags: переменные, linux

Как добавить в переменную $PATH в linux путь к gcc компилятору (/usr/gcc/4.4/bin)?

Comment: И как, все помогло? Все заработало?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А точно нужно добавлять? Если все установили правильно, то должно работать.
Но если хочется, то кто мешает открыть файл `~/.bashrc` и добавить где то в конец пару строк:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/gcc/4.4/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: @KoVadim, а где находится файл bashrc?

Comment: я же написал - `~/.bashrc`. Если в таком формате не понятно, то говорю по простому - это в домашнем каталоге. У Вас это наверно `/home/ivan31`. Обратите внимание на точку в начале файла!

Comment: @KoVadim, в каталоге home пусто.

Comment: может быть Вы под рутом работаете? тогда пробуйте `/root/.bashrc`
А лучше, скажите, какая именно версия какого именно линукса у Вас.

Comment: @KoVadim, Nexenta illumos.

Comment: я под рутом работаю и уже нашел /root/.bashrc

Comment: @KoVadim А зачем нужен export? Разве эта переменная уже ранее не экспортированна?

Answer (score 6):

Ответ посовременней:

```
# ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/gcc/4.4/bin"
```