# Переменная PATH слетает

Tags: bash

Завел переменную PATH_DATA в файле .profile. Код такой:
PATH_DATA=/home/Bekas/myfolder .
Распечатываю переменную:
echo $PATH_DATA -
путь не распечатывается. Пробовал зайти повторно в консоль - результат тот же. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить путь в переменную $PATH?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140785/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-path)

Comment: Не вижу прямой связи между заголовком и вопросом. У вас в .bash_profile существует? Если да, то он вызывается.

Comment: @0xdb видимо, проблема в отсутсвии `export`.

Comment: @mkkik Не думаю, .profile просто не вызывается. Что стоит в заголовке, полностью не соответствует тому, что стоит в теле вопроса. Т.ч. возможно не дубликат.

Comment: Вам же уже ответили на вопрос. Вам не помогло? Зачем так менять вопрос, делая его только менее понятным?

Answer (score 3):

цитата из самого файла `~/.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

вольный перевод существенного момента:

> этот файл не читается программой *bash*(1) если существует `~/.bash_profile` или `~/.bash_login`

---

ещё цитата, уже из `$ man 1 bash`, секция `invocation` (вызов):

> it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes  commands  from the first one that exists and is readable.

вольный перевод:

> программа считывает и выполняет команды из первого из существующих файлов: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` и `~/.profile`

Comment: Загнал определение переменной PATH_DATA  в .bash_profile, но безрезультатно. Открываю после закрытия bash-консоль, пишу echo $PATH_DATA - все та же пустая строка. Что делал. Пробовал писать PATH=[содержимое] export и PATH="[содержимое]" export - безрезультатно.

Comment: 1. вы как-то определитесь с именем переменной. вы упомянули в совокупности уже три имени: `PATH_DATA`, `DATA` и `PATH`. с третьей из них я бы не рекомендовал проводить эксперименты: её содержимое трактуется многими программами особым образом. 2. убедитесь, что у вас в роли оболочки выступает именно программа *bash*. 3. если вам надо менять переменную между запусками оболочки (без разлогинивания), да ещё и именно в интерактивном режиме, то лучше манипулировать файлом `~/.bashrc` — он прочитывается при каждом интерактивном запуске программы *bash*.

Comment: Извиняюсь, переменная окружения PATH_DATA. вывод после команды echo $0 дает -sh, то есть оболочка bash. Задача - сделать постоянную переменную, т.е. закрепить за ней директорию. Я считал, что подойдет .bash_profile (после коммента выше), но переменная стирается после выхода из оболочки и после повторного входа.

Comment: спасибо! Все сработало после того как я перенес содержимое переменной PATH_DATA=/home/Bekas/ в файл .bashrc.